# UI Automation Testing: How do I select UIAPickerWheel values?

Tags: ios, testing, ios4, uipickerview, ios-ui-automation

I've hit a roadblock in trying to write some automated tests for my iPhone app. Judging [from the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIAPickerWheelClassReference/UIAPickerWheel/UIAPickerWheel.html) I feel like this should select the first row of the first component of my UIPickerView:

```
var picker = UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow().pickers()[0];
var aWheel = picker.wheels()[0];
var someVals = aWheel.values();

aWheel.selectValue(someVals[0]);
```

But instead I get the following error, logged in Instruments:

```
       Exception raised while running script: - selectValue requires a valid value
```

Any ideas how I can

- Set predictable values on my UIPickerView cells/components? Currently, they all use custom UIViews, not the standard labels.

or

- Somehow get an array of values from my existing cells to iterate through?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3):

I also had this issue.

try `var newValue = someVals[0].toString();`

And then use the `newValue` to select your value in your picker:

`aWheel.selectValue(newValue);`

This worked for me

Answer (score 2):

For me the `selectValue` method on the picker wheel object didn't work if values in the wheel were empty, had spaces or had some special characters.  I ended up having to use `tapWithOptions({ tapOffset: { x: 0.23, y: 0.72 } })` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks correct. You need to add some checks though. I think your picker is empty, or you dont have a valid handler to it.
Here is how I do it my code. Hope it helps.

```
target      = UIATarget.localTarget();
app         = target.frontMostApp();
mainWindow  = app.mainWindow();


function selectOffice() {

    UIALogger.logStart("selectOffice");

    var validField = false;

    try {

        var picker = mainWindow.pickers()[0];

        if (picker.isValid()) {

            var wheel = picker.wheels()[0];

            if (wheel.isValid()){

                var pickedItems = wheel.values();
                var nrOfItems = pickedItems.length;

                if (nrOfItems > 0 ) {
                    wheel.selectValue(pickedItems[nrOfItems-1]);
                    validField = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch(error) {
        UIALogger.logFail(error);
    }

    if (validField == true ) {
        UIALogger.logPass("selectOffice");
    } else {
        UIALogger.logFail("Couldnt find a valid control");
    }
    target.delay(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`SelectValue()` does not seem to work for text-values.  It works for numeric, though.

For text-values, I just get the current value and tap until I find it.